# MaxLength for Integer field in Django

Tags: django

I want to limit the length of my integer field, but I don't want to use something like:

```
validators=[MaxValueValidator(999999999)]
```

What can I use instead of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own validator, for example:

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

class MaxLengthIntegerValidator(MaxValueValidator):
    def __init__(self, length):
        max_value = 10**length-1
        super(MaxLengthIntegerValidator, self).__init__(max_value)
```